# setup project without downloading .net framework from website?

Tags: c#

When i set prerequisite of my setup project I choose "Download prerequisite from the same location as my application".But when i run it at client(run setupfilename.msi),it requires me download .net frame from website.If i run setup.exe,it doesn't.Can anyone explain why and give me a some solutions.I used .Net Framewwork 2.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this.

1. Include .NET Framework 2.0 Setup .exe to your Setup Project.
2. Create a bath file that install .NET Framework 2.0 on client computer. (Link to included file)
3. Install your program.

NOTE

- Right Click on Setup Project > Add > File..., include .NET Framework 2.0 Setup .exe.
- Right Click on Setup Project > View > Custom Actions, include your bath file. (but I'm not sure .exe or .bat are work)